# Close all IE windows except 1 in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer

I'm using the following code to close all IE windows. This is part of error handling, when my larger function hangs or crashes, it automatically starts a new window. When that happens, I want to close all IE windows, except 1 (I want to keep that last one open to maintain the session, so the browser doesn't have to re-authenticate when it opens again).

Can I update the loop below so it closes all IE windows except for the last one (it doesn't matter which specific one it leaves open, just that it leaves one open).

```
Function closeallIE()
        Dim objWMI As Object, objProcess As Object, objProcesses As Object
        Set objWMI = GetObject("winmgmts://.")
        Set objProcesses = objWMI.ExecQuery( _
            "SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name = 'iexplore.exe'")
        For Each objProcess In objProcesses
            Call objProcess.Terminate
        Next
        Set objProcesses = Nothing: Set objWMI = Nothing
        Debug.Print wait(3)
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Count` property and use the PID with Taskkill:

```
Sub closeallIE()
    Dim objWMI As Object, objProcess As Object, objProcesses As Object
    Set objWMI = GetObject("winmgmts://.")
    Set objProcesses = objWMI.ExecQuery( _
        "SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name = 'iexplore.exe'")
    Dim j As Integer
    j = objProcesses.Count
    For Each objProcess In objProcesses
        If j > 1 Then Shell "taskkill /f /PID " & CStr(objProcess.ProcessID), vbHide

        j = j - 1
    Next
    Set objProcesses = Nothing
    Set objWMI = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work. I'm realizing the terminate command closes more Windows than intended which is why I'm seeing the wierd behaviour

Comment: Hm, makes sense. Then we need to get the PID and shut down only those instances one by one. See above code which works for me.

Comment: @SimaPro -- Did you see the solution? I edited the answer so that it does exactly what you need, using a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet taken from [HP UFT Website regarding closing browser tabs](http://community.hpe.com/t5/Unified-Functional-Testing/How-to-close-google-chrome-browser-tabs-one-by-one-at-a-time/m-p/6048969/highlight/true#M4189).
This works without any tweaks and uses creation time to close all tabs except the oldest by creation time.

```
On error resume next

Set oDesc = Description.Create
oDesc( "micclass" ).Value = "Browser"

oDesc( "application version" ).Value = browserPropertyApplicationVersion

Set vIE= Desktop.ChildObjects(oDesc)
vIECount=vIE.count

z=vIECount
For m=1To vIECount - 1
z=z-1
    If Browser("creationtime:="&z).Exist(0) Then

            Browser("creationtime:=1").Close

    End If


If err.number > 0 Then
message = message & " @@@@@@@Error shown by application is :  " & err.description
icon_flag=0
End If
Next

Set oDesc = Nothing
Set vIE=Nothing
```